# How to convince Flow that a type A is a subtype of an abstract type B without changing the definition of A?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Consider a class `A`:

```
class A { }
```

Is it possible to declare an abstract type `B`, and declare that `A` is a subtype of `B`, *without* changing the definition of `A`? I.e. the following should compile:

```
function f(b: B) { }
f(new A());
```

Rationale: I'm generating JavaScript code with Flow annotations from a language that supports a system similar to protocols a la Clojure and Elixir.

Comment: have you tried `A.prototype = new B();A.prototype.constructor = A;`

Comment: @MichaelDibbets `B` is abstract; it doesn't exist at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use interfaces? Interfaces use structural subtyping. So if you have

```
interface B {
  someProperty: string;
}
```

Then anything with the `string` property `someProperty` is a subtype of `B`.

```
class A {
  someProperty: string;
}

// No error
function testClassSubTyping(a: A): B {
  return a;
}

class C {}

// Error: property `someProperty` not found in C
function testBadClassSubTyping(c: C): B {
  return c;
}
```